# What are the different pillars of Hinduism?

Tags: sects

What are those different pillars of Hinduism? How many sects are there? How many maths? Are the rituals as per cultural practices of the land or based on scriptures?

Comment: There are too many questions. Please makenthem separate questions. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. In fact this crossed my mind. I would be grateful if the members can throw some light on the aspect of pillars in Hinduism. We know of that Vedas, Upanishads, Purans and Epics (Ramayana and Mahabharata) form the body of Hinduism. But what are the popular schools of thought or are those largely various sects?

Comment: Right now your question will be closed as too broad!! Kindly be specific and clear in 1 question you need answer!